# Download only specific directories from FTP site using wget

Tags: ftp, wget

I have read the manual page for `wget` and search Google for an answer, but haven't been able to get it.

How would I use `wget` to download only folders that contain a specific term in their names from an FTP site that also has multiple other directories without that term in their names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
wget -I /people,/cgi-bin http://host/people/bozo/
```

-I is followed by a comma separated list of the directories you want to include.

However, note that this will just include the full name listed in -I, I believe, not part of the name, it sounds like you may want to be including directories based on a partial pattern. If anyone knows how to do regex type excludes/includes with wget, I'd like to learn that, I've looked for that for years.

https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/html_node/Directory_002dBased-Limits.html